# Panda series to custom user defined JSON (performance is important)

Tags: python, json, pandas

I was trying to convert a pandas series to custom json format but having performance issues. Here's sample code to illustrate my problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.Series([np.Nan, 35.9, 0.0, -24.75, -45.5])
ix = pd.DatetimeIndex(start ='2018-07-01 10:00', freq ='10s', periods = 5)
data.index = ix

data
2018-07-01 10:00:00      NaN
2018-07-01 10:00:10    35.90
2018-07-01 10:00:20     0.00
2018-07-01 10:00:30   -24.75
2018-07-01 10:00:40   -45.50
Freq: 10S, dtype: float64
```

I need to create custom JSON out of this (see expected output). I tried below but found it very slow for bigger series -

```
def get_json_for_series(data):
    from collections import OrderedDict
    data.index = data.index.astype(str, copy=False)
    data = data.to_dict(OrderedDict)
    newTs = [{'timeMillis': int(pd.to_datetime(k).timestamp() * 1000), 'value': handle_nan_value(v)} for k,v in data.items()]
    return newTs



def handle_nan_value(v):
    if pd.isna(v) or v == 'null' :
        return ""
    else:
        return v
```

expected output :

```
[
  {
    "timeMillis": 1530439200000,
    "value": ""
  },
  {
    "timeMillis": 1530439210000,
    "value": 35.9
  },
  {
    "timeMillis": 1530439220000,
    "value": 0.0
  },
  {
    "timeMillis": 1530439230000,
    "value": -24.75
  },
  {
    "timeMillis": 1530439240000,
    "value": -45.5
  }
]
```

Any help is appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert series to dataframe and reset the index

```
data=pd.DataFrame(data).reset_index()
```

Change column names to desired output labels

```
data.columns=['timeMillis','value']

data

    timeMillis  value
0   2018-07-01 10:00:00 NaN
1   2018-07-01 10:00:10 35.90
2   2018-07-01 10:00:20 0.00
3   2018-07-01 10:00:30 -24.75
4   2018-07-01 10:00:40 -45.50
```

Use built-in `to_json` to go to json and use string replace to handle "null" values

```
data.to_json(orient='records').replace("null",'""')

'[{"timeMillis":1530439200000,"value":""},
{"timeMillis":1530439210000,"value":35.9},
{"timeMillis":1530439220000,"value":0.0},
{"timeMillis":1530439230000,"value":-24.75},
{"timeMillis":1530439240000,"value":-45.5}]'
```